# Continuous Percentage

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, statistics

This is probably super easy for the experts here (I need to retake and practice a lot of math courses, its been a while).

Suppose I have a shared bank account with N number of people. Anyone can add some amount to the account. Each person that adds money to the account needs to have a cumulative percentage that represents how much of the total balance they can lay claim to. So if 10 people add 10 dollars each, each person would own 10 percent of the account. If an 11th person comes in and adds 100 dollars, then the 11th person would own 50 percent of the account. However, the original percentages for the first 10 people are off now, since they would not own 10 percent of the total 200 dollars. Now everyones percentages would not be correct if you multiplied them times the total account value.

Other scenarios like, let's say a wealthy benefactor gives 250 dollars to the account and then the government comes in an takes 30 dollars from the entire account. This further confuses all the percentages

Is there anyway to keep a running percentage that each person owns without updating each ownage percentage for each person, everytime the account is changed ?

If you removed the 50% first, then did the lesser amounts it should work but is that the only way ?

Comment: Do you need to keep the running percentages? Wouldn't it be easier to just store the amounts each person holds and then calculate the percentage whenever it needs displaying?

Comment: If 10 people add 10 dollars each and then the total drops by 30 dollars, I wouldn't know each person has 10 percent of the 70 dollar total. How would I know they each owned 10 percent in this scenario ?

Comment: The total only drops when someone withdraws. And when someone withdraws, everyone's percentages change.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the total amount and each users amount of money. When you need the percentage for a specific person, use those two pieces of information to calculate the percentage when needed.

Comment: Because other things can cause the total to go up or down, I don't think your method would work. If 10 people add 10 dollars each and then the total drops by 30 dollars, I wouldn't know each person has 10 percent of the 70 dollar total. How would I know they each owned 10 percent in this scenario ?

Comment: If ten people have ten dollars each then the total clearly is $100$ dollars.

Comment: The total amount of money people have in the bank can only drop by $30$ if a few people collectively withdraw $30$, in which case the total is $70$ and a person having $10$ in the bank would own $\frac{10}{70}\approx14.2\%$